# Create For Loop To Predict Next Value Over Group (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, time-series

I am working on a project where I need to take groups of data and predict the next value for that group using a time series model.  In my data, I have a grouping variable and a numeric variable.

Here is an example of my data:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [
    ["A", 10],
    ["B", 10],
    ["C", 15],
    ["D", 12],
    ["A", 18],
    ["B", 19],
    ["C", 14],
    ["D", 22],
    ["A", 20],
    ["B", 25],
    ["C", 12],
    ["D", 30],
    ["A", 36],
    ["B", 27],
    ["C", 10],
    ["D", 45]
]


data = pd.DataFrame(
    data,
    columns=[
        "group",
        "value"
    ],
)
```

What I want to do is to create a for loop that iterates over the groups and predicts the next value for A, B, C, and D.  Essentially, my end result would be a new data frame with 4 rows, one for each new predicted value.  It would look something like this:

```
group pred_value
A     40
B     36
C     8
D     42
```

Here is my attempt at that so far:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AutoReg
final=pd.DataFrame()
for i in data['group']:
    group = data[data['group']==i]
    model = AutoReg(group['value'], lags=1)
    model_fit = model.fit()
    yhat = model_fit.predict(len(group), len(group))
    final = final.append(yhat,ignore_index=True)
```

Unfortunately, this produces a data frame with 15 rows and I'm not sure how to get the end result that I described above.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?  Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `groupby` first and then iterate. We can store the results in a `dict` and after the loop convert it to a DataFrame:

```
# will hold the predictions
forecasts = {}

# in each turn e.g., group == "A", values are [10, 18, 20, 36]
for group, values in data.groupby("group").value:
    # form the model and fit
    model = AutoReg(values, lags=1)
    result = model.fit()

    # predict
    prediction = result.forecast(steps=1)
    
    # store
    forecasts[group] = prediction

# after `for` ends, convert to DataFrame
all_predictions = pd.DataFrame(forecasts)
```

to get

```
>>> all_predictions

           A          B         C          D
4  51.809524  28.561404  7.285714  62.110656
```

---

We can also do this all with `apply`:

```
>>> data.groupby("group").value.apply(lambda x: AutoReg(x, lags=1).fit().forecast(1))

group
A      4    51.809524
B      4    28.561404
C      4     7.285714
D      4    62.110656
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

However, we potentially lose the ability to hold references to the fitted models, whereas in explicit `for`, we could keep them aside. But if that is not wanted anyway, this can be used.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This worked for the example I placed above.  However, when I subbed out my variable and dataset names in the data.groupby("group").value line (data, group, value), I got the following error message: ValueError: maxlag should be < nobs.  The lag I put in the model was 1 and this would suggest I have no data.  Not sure what is going wrong.  My data has same exact structure to the example data I posted above.

Comment: In my dataset, I have over 3000 groups and 12 values per group if thats helpful for context.

Comment: @user2813606 I see, can you run these and observe the result please: `s = df.groupby("group").value.size().le(1); print(s[s].index.tolist())`. This checks the names of the groups that have less than or equal to 1 value attached to them. Is this non-empty?

Comment: I see now!  There were 41 groups with no data - that is as expected.  Thank you!